# AWS Network ACL makes targets unhealthy

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a public and private subnet. Public subnet `subnet-public` contains an ALB and some instances (as a target group). Private subnet `subnet-private` contains a database.

The security groups are configured as follows. There are no NACLs defined.

```
1) sg-lb (SG associated to the ALB):
   ----------------------------------
   Inbound:
      HTTP with source 0.0.0.0/0
      HTTPS with source 0.0.0.0/0

   Outbound: 
      HTTP with destination `sg-web`

2) sg-web (SG associated to the EC2 instances and should only receive traffic from the ALB):
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Inbound:
      HTTP with source `sg-lb`
      HTTPS with source `sg-lb`

   Outbound: 
      All traffic with destination 0.0.0.0/0 

3) sg-private (SG associated to the db):
   ------------------------------------
   Inbound:
      Port 5432 with source `sg-web`

   Outbound: 
      All traffic with destination 0.0.0.0/0
```

The health checks (port 80) are working fine.

However, the moment I create a NACL for `subnet-private` the instances in the target group become unhealthy. That NACL looks as follows:

```
Inbound:
    Port 5432 from `subnet-public`

Outbound
    Port 0-65535 to `subnet-public`

This NACL is associated to `subnet-private`.
```

The health checks are between the ALB and the instances, all in the `subnet-public`. As far as I know, they have nothing to do with the `subnet-private` and hence also the NACL should not affect the health checks. Yet they become unhealthy.

The moment I redefine the NACL to allow all traffic inbound (source 0.0.0.0/0) and outbound (destination 0.0.0.0/0) the targets become healthy again.

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need to modify nacls? Usually SG are enough for traffic control.

Comment: Layered security in case someone heavily messes up with SGs

Comment: Are you sure that the NACL is onlly associated with that one specific subnet?

Comment: Yes, absolutely sure. The NACL is associated to the private subnet. I don't understand why a healthcheck between ALB and EC2 instances are being affected by a NACL defined on a private subnet.

Comment: Do they only become health when **both** inbound & outbound rules are restored, or is just one of them sufficient (try both separately)? That will help you track down what traffic might be being rejected.

Comment: Mistery solved: Apparently the web app was giving an error on the healthcheck if the database port and redis was not allowed. If both ports are open, then the app returns a proper response and the healthchecks are OK.